# AppleScript to find domain of the sender of mail and add it to the rules

Tags: macos, email, applescript

This is to deal with spam. now I know better, every time we open a spam email, spammer knows that the email id is valid. Marking it spam or doing anything is of no help.

Now my question. I am looking for help with my Applescript.

### Here is the logic I want to follow when I run the script

Find the sender email id
parse to get domain name ( I am stuck here)

### add the domain name to a particular mail rule "Addedfilter" as condition (this is optional would be great if I can automate this part)

I intend to use this through service of mail so the domain names of the sender ids are collected into my mail rule.

```
tell application "Mail"
   set theSelection to selection
   set theMessage to item 1 of theSelection
   set theSender to sender of theMessage
   --set theDomain to (do shell script "cut -f1 -d'@' $1" & quoted form of theSender)
   set theDomain to (do shell script "awk -F\"@\" '{print $2}'" & quoted form of theSender)

   display dialog theDomain
end tell
```

PS: Marking "junk mail" is not helping. Also I have some incentive to capture the junk mail domain ids.

Comment: In Mail's preferences, you can prevent Mail from loading pictures automatically when you open e-mail. That will also prevent Mail to load everything else that's on-line rather than in the e-mail. This should be sufficient to not contact spammer's server and load a beacon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the domain:

```
set theDomain to (do shell script "echo  " & quoted form of rich text 1 through -2 of theSender & " | awk " & quoted form of "{split($0,a,\"@\"); print a[2]}")
```

or this:

```
set theDomain to (do shell script "echo  " & quoted form of rich text 1 through -2 of theSender & " | awk -F \"@\" '{print $2}' $1")
```

Then, if you want to add the domain condition to your rule, do this:

```
set r to rule "Addedfilter"
tell r
   make new rule condition at end of rule conditions with properties {expression:theDomain, qualifier:does contain value, rule type:from header}
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the domain now.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the domain:

```
    set theSelection to selection
    set theMessage to item 1 of theSelection
    set theEmail to extract address from sender of item 1 of theMessage
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "@"   
    set theDomain to text item 2 of theEmail
```

Found it here:
https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/extract-domain-name-from-current-email-and-open-in-safari/2904/5